# Matplotlib: Times New Roman appears bold

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason when using Times New Roman in my `mpl` plots it appears bold. Other fonts are OK.

Here is a minimal example, and the result (inside a Word document, for comparison with what I expect Times New Roman to look like).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with plt.style.context('word'):
  fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(3.4, 2.1))
  ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
  ax1.plot([1,2,3,4,5], '+--')
  ax1.text(0.5, 3.5, r"Brown $\alpha + 12 \sum_ix$")
  ax1.text(0.5, 3, r"1.0 2.0")
  ax1.set_xlabel('normal 1.0 and math $1.0$')
  ax1.set_ylabel('Times New Roman')
  plt.tight_layout()
  fig.savefig('word.pdf')
```

with the `word` stylesheet containing

```
backend: PS
text.usetex: False
font.family: serif
font.serif: Times New Roman
font.size: 11
axes.titlesize: 11
axes.labelsize: 11
```

The plot is included in the document with its actual size (3.4'' by 2.1'').

The font is correctly found and it is also working in math-mode (see the alpha in the plot). It just seems that this is bold...

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Digging into more details I realized that the bug is real and that `mpl` is actually selecting a Times New Roman Bold font.

The font selection algorithm in `font_manger.py` assigns weights on every font it finds based on the family, variant, weight, etc. (around line 1290). The "name" coming from `Times New Roman Bold.ttf` is just 'Times New Roman' which might make sense, but the weight is 500, the same value as the regular font:

```
<Font 'Times New Roman' (Times New Roman Bold.ttf) normal normal 500 normal> with score 0.1
<Font 'Times New Roman' (Times New Roman.ttf) normal normal 500 normal> with score 0.1
```

On my Mac and Linux setup the bold one is encountered first and is selected by the code

```
 if score < best_score:
     best_score = score
     best_font = font
```

I dirty patch is to replace `<` by `<=`...

Comment: This worked for me on Mac OS Catalina. Seems to me like the least disruptive way of handling this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nearly 5 years later this bug is still there, and your dirty fix still solves the problem :) Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I know the question is very old, but it still is a problem, at least for me on my mac. I found a very easy solution to this problem, posted by azag0 on github

```
del matplotlib.font_manager.weight_dict['roman']
matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
```

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5574

Comment: Still a problem for me (matplotlib 3.03, on linux if that makes a difference).  This fix worked great.

Comment: Still a problem for me (matplotlib 3.10.0 on windows). DO NOT USE THIS ANSWER! This completely killed my font manager. Even completely reinstalling anaconda (with removing all users/.matplotlib/ etc folders) did not make it work again. Now I always get the error `'Font family ['serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.'` No serif fonts at all working now.

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced this problem when the matlibplot updated from 2.2.3 to 3.1.0. 
I tried a lot of answers here and from other websites, but the font "times new roman" still appeared bold. But I remembered last time when it was still 2.2.3, the font appeared normal. So I just replaced the font_manager.py in the 3.1.0 by the font_manager.py in the 2.2.3:

copy the font_manager.py in ..\anaconda\pkgs\matplotlib-2.2.3-py37hd159220_0\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib

and paste it here:          ..\anaconda\pkgs\matplotlib-3.1.0-py37hc8f65d3_0\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the font selection algorithm picks the first font in the Time New Roman family, which has four different files (bold, bold italic, italic and regular). So the steps would be:

1. Go to `C:\Windows\Fonts\Times New Roman`
2. Right-click → Sort by → Descending (the order will change so the Times New Roman Regular will end up as the first, and that will be the font the algorithm will choose).

Answer (score 0):

Removing `~/.cache/matplotlib/` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the timesbd.tff in matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts. And I'm not sure whether timesbi.tff and timesi.tff need to be deleted, but I did it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above the default font weighting is high for Times New Roman font in mpl (claim was 500 above, which I will take their word for it).

The easy fix for this is to set the weighting yourself using fontweight.

```
plt.xlabel('t',fontsize=32, fontname = 'Times New Roman', fontweight = 250)
```

This worked for me and looked normal.

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.7 on Windows 10, Jupyter Notebook, no Anaconda installed.

Simply adjusted the font sequence `C:\Windows\Fonts\Times New Roman` as suggested above doesn't work here.

Under
`C:\User\Name\.matplolib`, find a JSON File (text file) named `fontlist-v300`.

Delete

```
{
      "fname": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\timesbd.ttf",
      "name": "Times New Roman",
      "style": "normal",
      "variant": "normal",
      "weight": "roman",
      "stretch": "normal",
      "size": "scalable",
      "__class__": "FontEntry"
}
```

in the text file works for me.

Not a good way, though.